# Book Search in Careers 2.0 Profile broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, books

Is the Book search in Careers broken? I can't find anything, based on author search, title search, or ISBN searching?

Comment: Indeed, it looks like there was a change to the Amazon API. Stand by...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed, and thanks for the heads-up. Try again?